# Parenthesis in child route angular2

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

How can i ignore parenthesis in child routes. Here is my code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ShareComponent } from './share.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: 'share/list/:id/:title', component: ShareComponent },
      { path: 'share/list/:id', component: ShareComponent },

   ])
  ]
})

export class ShareRoutingModule { }
```

It works fine as long as there is no parenthesis in id or title value.

How can i handle if some one enters parenthesis in id or title value as they are dynamic and any one can enter any value.

Kindly ask me if you need more details. Thanks

Comment: You can provide a custom UrlSerializer. Parenthesis are used for aux routes and can't be ignored. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/UrlSerializer-class.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Can you please explain a lil more how i can do that, i saw the link you provided but couldn't understand. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, haven't used that myself yet. If you provide a custom serializer, this one is used instead the one provided by Angular itself. You can take the `DefaultUrlSerializer` as template.

Answer (score 3):

That's because of Auxiliary Routing.It's the default behaviour in angular. It helps to pass data to specific router-outlet. That's very frustration when i faced it.

SOLUTION :

Solve it by overriding UrlSerializer.

EXAMPLE :

> create a file **custom-url-serializer.ts**

```
import { UrlSerializer, UrlTree, DefaultUrlSerializer } from '@angular/router';

export default class CustomUrlSerialize implements UrlSerializer {

defaultUrlSerializer = new DefaultUrlSerializer();

parse(url: string): UrlTree {
    /** 
     You can replace or remove anything from the url as u want
     for ex in this case: 
     /home/hello(world) will become /home/hello%28world%29
    **/

    url = url.replace(/\(/g, '%28').replace(/\)/g, '%29');

    return this.defaultUrlSerializer.parse(url);
}

serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {

    // Decode it back to its original string
    return this.defaultUrlSerializer
               .serialize(tree)
               .replace(/%28/g, '(').replace(/%29/g,')');
}
```

and then add this as a provider in you **app.module.ts**

```
import { CustomUrlSerialize } from path-to-the-file // Import the file

const customUrlSerializer = new CustomUrlSerialize();

const CustomUrlSerializerProvider = {
  provide: UrlSerializer,
  useValue: customUrlSerializer
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [CustomUrlSerializerProvider] // <-- Add this as a provider
})

export class AppModule { }
```

After compiling when you go to the url http://localhost:4200/hello(world) it wont throw "**Cannot match any routes. URL Segment Error**".

Hope it helps someone! :-)

Comment: No, It's not fixed in Angular 8. I am still facing the same issue. I think it poses a security issue in Firefox. That's why the angular team didn't change it.

Comment: it works like a charm angular ver 9+ thank u so much.

Comment: nope, on 9.1 issue still present (SSR crashes, UI redirects to main page)